# What benefit is there in using artisan auth:clear-resets? Does it prevent certain issues or only maintains table size?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent, laravel-artisan, change-password

Does `artisan auth:clear-resets` do anything besides clearing the password_resets table? Does this affect the functionality of the password reset system?

I've been having some problems where our users trigger a password reset but as soon as they click through in the provided email they get an "invalid token" notice. I use `artisan auth:clear-resets` and it seems that the complaints go away...

It could be a coincidence but I was wondering if there was an underlying benefit to clearing the password_resets table that I'm unfamiliar with

Answer (score 0):

You can get that message if the token expires before it is used.

Token age is defined in `config/auth.php` under the "Resetting Passwords" section, maybe the time should be extended for your use case?

The docs show a scheduled job running every 15 minutes to run `auth:clear-resets`. However, all this does is delete expired tokens from the database. You should be running *at least* once a day via your scheduler defined in `app/Console/Kernel.php`.

https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/passwords#deleting-expired-tokens

Comment: Thanks for your comment... unfortunately, our expirations are set to 24 hours, but the token expired message comes up even when the reset is triggered and accessed within seconds, although the problem is sporadic, so hard to diagnose.

Comment: It is safe to run clear-resets more often than your expiration.  It is pruning expired records from the database.  If that is fixing your issue when you run it from the CLI, then having your scheduler run it every 5 minutes may be helpful (assuming you have your scheduler configured to run as well).  The reset-token system is pretty well tested so I'd look at any customizations made as the culprit.  I'd also recommend verifying the issue is real if you haven't already. (Is the user using the latest token sent to their email? Does this token have unexpected symbols? etc)

Comment: I'll try adding it to the scheduler and see if the issues persist.

My first thought with this kind of problem is that it's user error, but we've confirmed that it's a real issue several times now. 

I'll have to dig into the logs and try to recreate the circumstances. Thank you for your responses.